# Input value from element within a class into an onclick

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

How can I input a value pulled from an element within a class into an `onclick` function?

The following is the resulting code I am looking to obtain:

```
<span class="total-sum"><span>2 790.00</span> USD</span>

<span onclick="calculate_cart(68803,2790.00);">GO</span>
```

Notice the `2 790.00` from the first element has its space removed and is placed into the `onclick`.

This is some JS I wrote which successfully pulls `2 790.00 and removes the spaces:

`.querySelector( ".total-sum span" ).textContent.replace( /\s/g, "");`

I am stuck on how to place the code into the `onclick` itself.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of replacing the `onclick` attribute text, why don't you pull the contents of `.total-sum span` directly in `calculate_cart`?

```
function calculate_cart(some_id) {
  var total_sum = document.querySelector(".total-sum span").textContent.replace(/\s/g, "");
  // the rest of `calculate_cart`
}
```

And then you don't need the second parameter:

```
<span onclick="calculate_cart(68803);">GO</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use it like this if you need it inline:

```
  <span onclick="calculate_cart(68803,document.querySelector('.total-sum span' ).textContent.replace( /\s/g, ''));">GO</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass values as parameters:

```js
function myFunction(x, y){
    console.log('x: ' + x + ' y: ' + y);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="fields" value="2300"/>
<input type="text" class="fields" value="100"/>
<button onclick='myFunction(document.getElementsByClassName("fields")[0].value, document.getElementsByClassName("fields")[1].value)'>do function</button>
```